# Potential Bug in Postgres Subqueries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

We are running the following select statement on postgres 10 and 11 and notice unexpected behaviour while processing the subquery

See example:

**Correct query**

--> subquery column name exists in subquery

```
select * from information_schema."tables" t
where t.table_schema in (select schemaname from pg_tables t2);
```

**Error no column schemaname2**

--> subquery column name does not exists in both tables

```
select * from information_schema."tables" t
where t.table_schema in (select schemaname2 from pg_tables t2);
```

**NO Error although the column table_schema does not exist in pg_tables**

--> subquery column name does not in exists in subquery but in main query -> all rows from the main query are selected

```
select * from information_schema."tables" t
where t.table_schema in (select table_schema from pg_tables t2);
```

**Error due to the use of table alias**

--> our proposed workaround -> always use aliases then postgres is forced to validate column name

```
select * from information_schema."tables" t
where t.table_schema in (select t2.table_schema from pg_tables t2);
```

Special thx to https://stackoverflow.com/users/8579285/oved-s for verification and constant support

Comment: Check if this can help: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/bug-reporting.html

Comment: Not a bug, this is how it's required by the SQL standard. See also here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/218871/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That is some interesting behavior! I'm assuming it's performing a correlated subquery since the column name must match a column name in the outer query. Since no correlation is specified it's cross joining giving a positive hit for all records. This explains why the Alias fails.

Comment: If the column doesn't exist in the scope of the sub-query the SQL standard mandates that a column with that name from the outer query should be used. The query that works in your example (but shouldn't) is essentially the same as `where t.table_schema = table_schema` (instead of a IN condition)